Was Wormtail the only Gryffindor in the Voldemort camp?
As most of Voldemort's camp was filled with Slytherin people, was there any other known Gryffindor other than Peter Pettigrew (Wormtail)?
Few names that comes to my mind that doesn't look like Slytherins are Barty Crouch Jr, Stan Shunpike, Pius Thicknesse etc.
P.S. I know of this question. My question is specifically about the 2 wizard wars only.

Crouch Jr: Unknown - Stan Shunpike: Unknown - Pius Thicknesse: Unknown

Also, I still think this is dupe, if the other question can or can't find any Gryffindors, limiting this question to smaller subset would yield the same or fewer results.

Was Pius actually a Death Eater? I thought that he was under the Imperius Curse
